# Is there a way to change column name before fetching data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is there a way to change column name before fetching data in all the controllers I call that column from, for example I had 2 columns in my table "Section" : "Title" and "TitleEN"

If the current culture is "en", I want to fetch "TitleEn" data but in my code I'll only use "Title" like this:

```
      section.Where(p => 
      p.Title.ToUpper().Contains(searchword.ToUpper()));
```

I was working on a project with only one language and then the client requested adding English. Unfortunately I made the wrong decision by adding language fields for every table having string fields.

Now I want to fix this because the project has a lot of code dealing only with fields without "En".

Comment: This approach for internationalization sounds like it's going to result in *many* identical conditions/switches/etc. all over the code.

Comment: So, there is no easy way to fix this !!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure on how this is being called, but you could be a bit sneaky on the entity itself.  I think you are saying that you are always using the Title property on the entity, but you need it to be EN when the culture is set to EN.  If you don't mind selecting both values every time on every query, there is an easy fix for this.

In your entity, I would do something like this:

```
public class MyEntity
{
   [Column("Title")]  // Can use FluentApi here instead
   public string TitleOld { get; set; }

   [Column("TitleEN")]
   public string TitleEN { get; set; }

   [NotMapped]
   public string Title 
   { 
     get { return Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name == "en-US" ? TitleEN : TitleOld; }
     set { TitleOld = value; }
   }
}
```

This way, your code wouldn't change, but you'd be selecting both values down every time.

Comment: That is exactly what I made but without [NotMapped] and removing set in "Title" field

Comment: I wasn't going to do Set, but if you had code that was also updating Title property, then this would make that still work, too.  Also, you can do Ignore in FluentApi if you prefer that style. :)

Answer (score 0):

not the best solution, but you can just use an If currentcul is En, then

```
 section.Where(p => 
      p.TitleEN.ToUpper().Contains(searchword.ToUpper()));
    Else{
section.Where(p => 
      p.Title.ToUpper().Contains(searchword.ToUpper()));
    }
```

I would recommend using a diffrent solution tho.

Comment: i guess you could also just momentarely before your send your model to the view change the Model Title to be equal to TitleEn.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work

```
var section = new List<Test>();
var result = section.Where(x => (System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name.Equals("en") 
                                            && x.TitleEn.ToUpper().Contains(searchword.ToUpper())) 
                                     || (!System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name.Equals("en") 
                                     && x.Title.ToUpper().Contains(searchword.ToUpper())));
```